# Docker save gzip "Error response from daemon: invalid reference format" only with Process.start() in C#, works from CMD

Tags: c#, docker

I am trying to export container image on Windows OS.

I have sample command:

```
docker save myimatetest:latest > C:\temp.tar.gz
```

and it's working when I execute it via command line, but when I try to invoke the same command using C#'s Process class it's crashing with:

> Error response from daemon: invalid reference format

This is the code I'm using:

```
Process process = new Process();
StringBuilder outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();
StringBuilder errorBuilder = new StringBuilder();

string workDir = Path.GetDirectoryName(@"F:\mydirdockerfilelocation");

process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = workDir;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "docker";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"save myimatetest:latest > C:\temp.tar.gz";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        outputBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};

process.ErrorDataReceived += (sender, e) =>
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        errorBuilder.AppendLine(e.Data);
    }
};


process.Start();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();

process.ExitCode.Dump();
outputBuilder.Dump();
errorBuilder.Dump();
```

Have you got any idea what could cause it?

Comment: Can you use a [Docker SDK](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/sdk/) instead of the subprocess call?  It looks like [Docker.DotNet](https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet) supports a `client.Images.SaveImageAsync` method.

Comment: when you say `it's working when I execute it via command line`, can you specify which command line are you using? windows cmd prompt, or powershell, or some bash-like shell?

Comment: @LeiYang C:\Windows\system32>cmd version
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17763.2061]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use standard output redirection here but need to specify the output file name using the -o option

```
process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"save -o C:\temp.tar myimatetest:latest";
```

Comment: this is official command on docker site with using gzip:
docker save myimage:latest | gzip > myimage_latest.tar.gz, providen command by you isn't using gzip?

Comment: You can't use a pipe like that. Both the pipe | and the output redirection > are not part of the parameters of the docker command, so you cannot use them with the Process class

Comment: Is there any option how to use save with gzip using Process class at all? :(

Comment: You can call gzip separately afterwards to zip the file